# Best Practice: UIViewController or UIView

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I am gonna design a component in IOS, in which we will have Table view and Grid View; means user can see his data in table or grid. So what i am doing is i added a UIViewController and added two child view controller one for table and another one for collection view. I am handling everything using UIViewController only. Its means when user wants to use my component he has to add as a child view controller only. My question is that "Is it the best practice to use UIViewController like i am doing or Should I convert everything to UIView because UIView is light weight." I am gonna write only presentation logic in my component. We will get data from outside using delegate. And if i should use UIView then when should i use UIViewController?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your current approach is correct.

UIViews should do one and only one thing: paint a view when asked to.

UIViewControllers are more complex. They are are responsible for setting up views with any data they need to do their job, compositing multiple views (or view controllers) together if needed, responding to events from view components or from the device in general, and communicating with the rest of the code/system.

Because your code wants to show two different kinds of information, it fits the UIViewController much better than the plain UIView style.

As you've pointed out, Apple themselves have many examples of UIView subclasses that have delegates and do complex things. However, if you're writing a new component and it is complex (as yours is), I seriously recommend going for the UIViewController approach.

**A note on history:** Apple used to be of the advice that UIViewControllers should only show/composit UIViews and not other UIViewControllers (even though, confusingly, they didn't always follow their own advice!). This would align with their making of some quite complex UIView subclasses. However, they changed this stance a while back, and added support to UIViewControllers for compositing other UIViewControllers' views inside them. **If Apple's stance had always been as it is now, you might find that some of their UIView subclasses were implemented as UIViewControllers!**

As an experiment, it would probably be quite educational to try and implement your component both ways. I predict that you'd find UIView approach more unwieldy, with you having manually re-plumb some of the 'wiring' that you'd get 'for free' with the UIViewController approach.

Comment: Thanks Man for clear idea. But as you told "UIViews are usually configured with any info that is needed to do their job, as opposed to asking delegates for their info." But UITableView ask data using data source and delegate

Comment: That's an exception to the rule, you're right. I wouldn't advise following that example though! If something is in any way complex, make it a view controller, not just a view.

Comment: And in your example, you want to composit different views, from what I understand. That's a job for a UIViewController, not a UIView.

Comment: I've edited the part about delegates + UIViews in my answer, since there are plenty of examples of Apple using UIViews.

Answer (score 1):

Avoid putting logic in UIView subclass.

Comment: U mean to say i should use UIView because i am putting only presentation logic in my component

Comment: logic means how cell will look and tableview and grid presentation animation etc

Comment: by logic I mean everything else than display what is has been given as input. A view should not be aware of where it is or what is around or what happen if it is displayed or hidden or touched. It should just show its input. You can override its draw method for example.

Answer (score 0):

As I think you can make grid view by using table view just simply add multiple views on each cells

at time of switching grid to list or list to grid simply check your type and reload tableview

Comment: My question was not logical. I wanted to know as i am doing everything UIViewController thats fine or everything should be UIView. Which one is best practice

Comment: If your control will appear with new controller then  its fine either if that will be add on any screen then simply use UIView